# Can I add a web part to a product that will calculate price in the shopping cart?

Tags: kentico

I want to write a web part to calculate price, and have the customer enter data like Length and Width into a price calculation form , inside the shopping cart.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be that difficult to implement, however I would add those fields as text product options directly to given product. This makes much easier to calculate the price and you don't have to customize the shopping cart source files. With this approach all you need to do is override the **CalculateUnitPriceInternal(ShoppingCartItemInfo)** method according to our documentation:

[Custom Info Provider](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?custom_providers_info_example.htm)

Best regards,
Jan Hermann

Comment: I tried adding product option categories as you describe. How do I get them to display in the product in the shopping cart?